# noUIslider adjustment with plus and minus buttons on slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, nouislider

Has anyone included anchor tags as a plus and minus function to increase and decrease your value on the slider of the noUIslider? I haven't found anything related to this using the noUIslider yet, but I'm in hopes someone has done it before. I have an example of one of my sliders when they're created below.

```
qdata['calc-rate'] = {value:4,type:"percent",decimals:3,post:"%",interface:"slider",min:0,max:10,inc:.125,label:'Interest Rate',display:''};
  var f = qdata['calc-rate'];
  var val = f['value'];
  var sliderInterest = document.getElementById("paymentSliderInterest");
    noUiSlider.create(sliderInterest, {
      start:val,
      behaviour:'tap',
      range:{'min':0,'max':10},
      connect:"lower",
      step:f.inc,
      format: wNumb({decimals: f.decimals})
    });
  sliderInterest.noUiSlider.on('slide', setInterestSliderDisplay);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function incRateSlider(e){
 // changes slider rate value using plus and minus buttons
 if(e){ e.preventDefault(); }
 var f = qdata['calc-rate'];
 var id = $(this).attr("id");
 var dir = 1;
 if(id == "leftCircleRate"){ dir = -1; }    
 //console.log(f.value);    

 var newval = +f.value + +(dir * f.inc);// add or subtract values
 if(newval > f.max){ newval = f.max;}
 else if(newval < f.min){ newval = f.min; } 

 var slider = document.getElementById('paymentSliderInterest');
 slider.noUiSlider.set(newval); //this sets the value for the slider "super necessary"
 setInterestSliderDisplay(newval);  
}
```

Since I had my own array of data set for the required pieces of 'calc-rate' it was able to use the 'f.inc' to increase or decrease based on the selected id to move the slider one step at a time. If there isn't enough clarity on how this works just let me know so I can edit more of it to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

There is "**noUiSlider.get()**" and "**noUiSlider.set()**" methods available to let you achieve this. I have done this for date and amount. Please have a look at code below and let me know if you have any question.

**Please don't forget to have a look at stepSize variable in my script below. You can customise step size. In date you can select Year or Month. Hope this helpful to someone.**

**Simple number or amount**

```js
var connectSlider = document.getElementById('slider-connect');

noUiSlider.create(connectSlider, {
    start: 100,
    connect: [true, false],
    range: {
        'min': 0,
        'max': 500
    },
    step : 1,
    tooltips: wNumb({decimals: 0, suffix: 'K'}),
    format: wNumb({decimals: 0})
});



connectSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function (values, handle) {
    document.getElementById('event-start').innerHTML = values[0] + "K";
    
    //var myVal = connectSlider.noUiSlider.get();
    
    
});

function manualStep (direction){
 
    
  var currentPosition = parseInt(connectSlider.noUiSlider.get());
    var stepSize = 100;
    
    if(direction == 'f'){
     currentPosition += stepSize;
    }
    if(direction == 'b'){
     currentPosition -= stepSize;
    }
    
   currentPosition = (Math.round(currentPosition / stepSize) * stepSize);
    
    
     connectSlider.noUiSlider.set(currentPosition);
    
}
document.getElementById('stepforward').onclick = function() {manualStep("f")};
document.getElementById('stepback').onclick = function() {manualStep("b")};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/12.0.0/nouislider.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/12.0.0/nouislider.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wnumb/1.1.0/wNumb.js"></script>
  


 <p>
 Some Amount 
 </p>
<div id="slider-connect"></div>
<div class="example-val" id="event-start">34</div>
<div class="example-val" id="event-end"></div>
<button id="stepback">Decrease</button>
<button id="stepforward">Increase</button>
```

**Date Slider**

```js
// Create a new date from a string, return as a timestamp.
function timestamp(str) {
    return new Date(str).getTime();
}

var dateSlider = document.getElementById('slider-date');
var dateNow = timestamp(Date.now());
noUiSlider.create(dateSlider, {
// Create two timestamps to define a range.
    range: {
        min: timestamp('2012'),
        max: timestamp(dateNow)
    },

// Steps of one week
    step: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,

// Two more timestamps indicate the handle starting positions.
    start: timestamp('2015'),
    
    
    connect: [true, false],
    
    tooltips: true,

// No decimals
    format: { to: toFormat, from: Number }
});

function toFormat ( v ) {
 return formatDate(new Date(v));
}

var dateValues = [
    document.getElementById('event-start'),
    document.getElementById('event-end')
];

dateSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function (values, handle) {
     dateValues[handle].innerHTML = values[handle]; 
    
});





// Create a string representation of the date.
function formatDate(date) {
// Create a list of day and month names.


var months = [
    "January", "February", "March",
    "April", "May", "June", "July",
    "August", "September", "October",
    "November", "December"
];

    return months[date.getMonth()] + ", " +
        date.getFullYear();

}


function manualStep (direction){
 
    
  var currentPosition = dateSlider.noUiSlider.get();
    
    var stepSize = 'month';
    
    currentPosition = new Date(currentPosition);
    
    if(stepSize === 'month'){
    
     if(direction === 'f'){
       currentPosition = new Date(currentPosition.setMonth(currentPosition.getMonth()+1));
      }
      if(direction === 'b'){
       currentPosition = new Date(currentPosition.setMonth(currentPosition.getMonth()-1));
      }
      
    }
    
    if(stepSize === 'year'){
     if(direction === 'f'){
       currentPosition = new Date(currentPosition.setFullYear(currentPosition.getFullYear()+1));
      }
      if(direction === 'b'){
       currentPosition = new Date(currentPosition.setFullYear(currentPosition.getFullYear()-1));
      }
    }    
     dateSlider.noUiSlider.set(currentPosition);
    
}
document.getElementById('stepforward').onclick = function() {manualStep("f")};
document.getElementById('stepback').onclick = function() {manualStep("b")};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/12.0.0/nouislider.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/12.0.0/nouislider.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wnumb/1.1.0/wNumb.js"></script>
  


<p>
Some date:
</p>
<div id="slider-date"></div>
<div class="example-val" id="event-start"></div>
<div class="example-val" id="event-end"></div>

<button id="stepback">Decrease</button>
<button id="stepforward">Increase</button>
```

[JS Fiddle Link for Amount or Number](https://jsfiddle.net/concypt/nqu05ha3/71/)
[JS Fiddle Link for Date](https://jsfiddle.net/concypt/ahoL3wk6/107/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [keypress example](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/examples/#section-keypress) from the documentation, but change the event from a `keypress` to a button click.

It uses the `step` option to get the next and previous step:

```
button.addEventListener('click', function( e ) {

    var values = keypressSlider.noUiSlider.get();
    var value = Number(values[handle]);

    // [[handle0_down, handle0_up], [handle1_down, handle1_up]]
    var steps = keypressSlider.noUiSlider.steps();

    // [down, up]
    var step = steps[handle];

    // set slider
    // ...
});
```

Comment: I tried using this methodology to apply to how my code functions with the noUIslider, but it became more complicated trying to apply it to the key press addEventListener. After some more dedicated time a solution was found with using your noUIslider.set method. Had no idea how easily it could have been done until I came across it. I answered my question, but I really appreciate the assistance.